# Why is output 4196208 when input is string in an integer variable?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    int z = x + y;
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << z;
}
```

Input is `k m`.
Output is `0 4196208 4196208`.

Comment: `x` and `y` are uninitialised since `cin >> x >> y` fails.  As a result, garbage values are printed.

Comment: Your compiler predates C++11 (or is running in a pre-C++11 mode).   Before C++11, a letter input where an integral value is expected, leaves the variable unchanged - in your case, both variables are uninitialised, so printing either (or both) of them gives undefined behaviour.   Since C++11,  such a failure to read will result in the values being set to zero.

Comment: Check to see if the input failed, `if (!(cin>>x>>y)) throw std::runtime_error("oopsies");`

Comment: @peter • I think that's why the `x` gets set to 0.  But since the stream is in a fail-state for reading `y`, I suspect `y` does not get initialized to 0.  (I tried it with a quick toy program, and that seems to be the behavior, with C++17.)

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you these values because you have defined `x` and `y` as an integer, but you are giving them characters when it asks for input.
It's not a valid operation.
It will just simply give an error in form of some random number.

Comment: I have intentionally given string input to integer variables. I wanted to know the reason behind printing of 4196208.

Comment: its just an undefined behavior u can't give string as input when u have defined your variable as integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `x` and `y` are not initialized, and `std::cin>> x >> y;` has failed because it expects an int and got a char, the behavior is undefined. It highly depends on the compiler. Your code on other compilers may give `0 0 0` as an output since the compiler has initialized `x` and `y` for you. On other compilers may give different value other than `4196208`

Try this code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=2,y=2;
    cin>>x>>y;
    int z=x+y;
    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<z;
    return 0;
}
```

The output gonna be `2 2 4`. Because `x` and `y` are initialized and the exception thrown by `std::cin` will be ignored and the execution will continue to evaluate the sum.

Note that `std::cin` is an `std::basic_istream` object. The `>>` operator is overloaded to return a reference to the stream itself that could be evaluated as a boolean. So you could write some code like this

```
if(!(std::cin>>x>>y)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for the answer!